# mysql query find between past dates and current dates

Tags: mysql

I have two tables one is simple like this named orders and due_dates

```
id | name | price | due_id | status
1    a      10       1         0
2    b      20       1         0
3    c      30       1         1
4    d      40       2         0
4    d      40       2         1
```

and an other table with dates

```
id | start_date | end_date
1    2011-04-01   2011-05-21
2    2011-07-01   2011-07-15
```

what I am trying to find is all orders from past period with status 0 and from the current period all records with status 0  and 1  i know how to get orders from current period

```
SELECT *
FROM orders
INNER JOIN due_dates ON orders.due_id = due_dates.due_id
    AND now() BETWEEN due_dates.start_date AND due_dates.end_date
    AND status in (0,1);
```

Comment: It looks like you only pasted part of your query in your question. Is something missing?

Comment: and your problem is ...?

Comment: added full query sorry i thought it would be batter if i post only problem

Comment: And the problem you're trying to solve is, you want a query that selects only orders from the most recently past period, in status 0?

Comment: yes current + all past period with status 0

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM orders
INNER JOIN due_dates ON orders.due_id = due_dates.due_id
WHERE
    (status in (0,1) and now() BETWEEN due_dates.start_date AND due_dates.end_date) OR
    (status = 0 AND  due_dates.end_date < now())
```

Comment: if i add a third table should i use group by? because it show's all records i guess that is because of or statement

Comment: @user828061 I don't know, it depends on what are you going to do. Anyway, I updated the query to be it more strict if this helps.